# I am trying to map images from an array and passing them as props. I am importing them in my component but i am getting broken image.Below is my code

Tags: reactjs

images are stored in assets in my src folder,
Putting src={weightloss} in Services.js shows the particular image multiple times but i want to show different images. Is there any way to map all the images

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Services from "./Services"
import {service} from "./service"
function App() {
return (
    <div className= 'service-cont'>
       {service.map((service) => {
        return <Services key={service.id} {...service}/>
       })}
 </div>
  
 );
}

export default App;
```

**Services.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./services.css";
import weightloss from '../assets/weightloss.jpg';
import weightgain from '../assets/weightgain.jpg';
import kids from '../assets/kids.jpg';

const Services = ({name,image}) => {
 console.log(image);
return (
    <div className="services">
        <h3> {name} </h3>
        <img src={image} />
        
      </div>
   );
} 
export default Services;
```

service.js

```
                 export  const service = [

                {id: 1,
                 name : 'WEIGHT LOSS',
                 image :'weightloss'
                 },

                 {id: 2,
                 name : 'WEIGHT GAIN',
                 image :'weightgain'
                 }, 
                  
               {id: 3,
                 name : 'KIDS CARE',
                 image :'kids'
                 }, 
            ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically coding this: `<img src={'weightloss'} />` which is totally incorrect.

In `Services` create a lookup object to map the mapped key to the imported image object.

```
import React from "react";
import "./services.css";
import weightloss from '../assets/weightloss.jpg';
import weightgain from '../assets/weightgain.jpg';
import kids from '../assets/kids.jpg';

const imageMap = {
  weightloss,
  weightgain,
  kids
};

const Services = ({ name, image }) => {
  return (
    <div className="services">
      <h3> {name} </h3>
      <img src={imageMap[image]} />
    </div>
  );
}
```